# Display data from MySQL to NSTableView

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I have a php file to select data from my database. I want to display my data into NSTableView. I don't know my php file is true or false? I posted my phpfile and 2 file .m .h in Xcode. Thanks very much!!!

my php file:

```
<?php
$DB_HostName = "localhost"; 
$DB_Name = "QM_TEST";           
$DB_User = "root";          
$DB_Pass = "";              

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query("set collation_connection='utf8'");

if(!$con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query("select * from EX");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = array();
if ($numrows!=0){
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $grade = $row['grade'];
    //echo "$name///";
    //echo "$grade///";

}

}else
    {
        echo "FAILED :(";   
    }
?>
```

my TableArray.h

```
@implementation TableArray

- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if(self) {

}
return self;
}
-(void)awakeFromNib{
[tableview1 setDataSource:self];
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
return [array1 count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn        *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
return (NSString * )[array1 objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

-(IBAction) list:(id)sender{
[array1 removeAllObjects];
NSString *strURL = @"http://localhost/phpFile1.php";

NSData *URLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSString *DataResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:URLData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *array = [DataResult componentsSeparatedByString:@"///"];
array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
[tableview1 reloadData];
NSLog(@"%@",array1);

}

@end
```

my TableArray.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TableArray : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource>{
IBOutlet NSTableView *tableview1;
NSMutableArray *array1;
}
-(IBAction) list:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: You should at least display the part where you instantiate the NSTableView...

Comment: Can you explain it for me? (sorry my English is bad)

Comment: You'll have to provide us with some code. Edit your question and explain exactly what the problem is. If you're looking for someone to write code for you, you'll don't find that here.. From what I see, you just keep $name and $grade, but I don't see anything that returns the data back to your iOS app.

Comment: Sorry about my question! I've edited my question. I hope you will help me. Thanks Brice!

Comment: I think my problem is return values in php file